# Writing SBT variable to resource

Tags: scala, sbt

What would be the easiest way of resolving some variable in SBT and storing it to resource file, so that it would be available in the runtime?

More specifically: how can I get the `version` value set up by `sbt-git` plugin and make it available not only as a part of the artifact/assembly JAR name, but also inside resource directory, so I could access it at runtime and e.g. print on output, or return as service version through some version endpoint of my web service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my code for getting the commit from plain `git` and store it along with the version of the project within a properties file `path/to/version.properties` available in the package `path.to`:

```
resourceGenerators in Compile <+= Def.task {
  import scala.sys.process._
  val file = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "path" / "to" / "version.properties"
  val gitHash = "git rev-parse HEAD".!!
  val gitStatus = "git status".!!
  IO.writeLines(file, Seq(
    s"project.version = ${version.value}",
    s"git.hash = $gitHash",
    s"build.date = ${new java.util.Date()}") ++
    gitStatus.split("\n").map("#" + _))
  Seq(file)
}⏎
```

Comment: Thanks! As a small note about what difference sbt-git makes, is that we can store `version.value` directly into the file, as sbt-git already took care of checking if it is released (through tags) is it a snapshot etc. But this answer could be useful to not only sbt-git users :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is usually to use the [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin.

In your `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.6.1")
```

Add the following in your build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)
buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion)
buildInfoPackage := "hello"
```

After reload and compile this generates a `BuildInfo.scala`, which allows you to access any settings you configured in `buildInfoKeys` at runtime.